# RPC call with Metamask

Tags: ethereum, rpc, web3js, json-rpc, metamask

I want to create an RPC call (study purpose) from my app using metamask.

My method on my contract is:

```
function sayHelloMyName(string memory _name) external pure returns (string memory) {      
        require(bytes(_name).length != 0, "insert your name");
        return string(abi.encodePacked("hello ", _name));
    }
```

its hash is:

```
$ web3.utils.keccak256("sayHelloMyName(string)").substr(0, 10)
> '0x10a7b27a'
```

I want to pass my name foo where the hex decimal is 0x666f6f

```sh
web3.utils.toHex('foo')
'0x666f6f'
```

So my call is:

```
ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_call',
      params: [
        {
          from: currentAccount,
          to: contractAddress,
          data: 0x10a7b27a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000666f6f
        }, "latest"],
    })
    .then((txHash) => {
      console.log(txHash);
      $('#info').html(txHash);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error;
      $('#info').text(JSON.stringify(error.message));
    });
```

where the data is the method signature, and my hex name and padding (total 32 bytes)
Unfortunately, I get a revert of it.

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "execution reverted"
    }
}
```

the code works, I can use it with web3 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity `string` is encoded as a dynamic-length array of bytes including the first 32byte slot pointing to the location of the array beginning and the second 32byte slot containing the length of the string. Meaning: **Not just the hex value** of the string that you're passing.

It works with `web3js` because the JS library **decodes** the hex back to string *(web3 assumes the input is hex as it starts with `0x`)*, and then **encodes** it correctly to the byte array while filling the `data` field.

See output of this `web3js` snippet

```
const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'sayHelloMyName',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'string',
        name: '_name'
    }]
}, [
    'foo',
]);
console.log(data);
```

that prints

```
# formatted for readability
0x10a7b27a
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
666f6f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

- First slot is a pointer to the location where the array starts. In this case (hex20 == dec32) that's beginning of the second slot.
- Second slot (value 3) is the length of the values
- And the third slot contains the actual hex-encoded value of the string

**Solution:** This long value (without the newlines) is what you need to pass instead.

Comment: Amazing, it's the answer that I'm looking for!

Comment: so, If I want to use `eth_sendTransaction` with metamask with value and data, I should create data with method signature (4 bytes) + params that I can create with [encodeParam](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameter) as you said, the value in hex wei.

Because with `web3.eth.sendTransaction` I need the Private key of the user, so I presume that sendTransaction is for "server-side"

Thanks for your time

Comment: honestly, I have doubts about hex20, the first slot, where can I find more info about it?

Comment: @foo_bar See `offset` about the first slot: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types